# Check wireless card manufacturer and model in Linux Mint 11

Tags: wireless-networking, linux-mint, wireless-adapter, system-info

I googled around but most instructions refer to older versions, in which there is a "Device Manager" program in the Control Center.

The closest I could find in Katya is "System Information", which lists network interfaces and stats about them, but not manufacturer and model, which are all I need now.

Any clues?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The terminal command `lspci -vq` will print a long list of installed hardware, including wireless card model.

Comment: Try something like `lspci -vq | grep -i wireless -B 1 -A 5` to look only for wireless cards.

Comment: `-vq` is meant to be human readable. Try one of the `-m`flags and select the parts you want. Like this: `lspci -vmm |sed -n '/wireless/I,/^$/p'`

Comment: @patricvacek   lspci -vq | grep -i wireless -B 1 -A 5   retuns nothing. What does that mean.

Comment: just to note, this can't find my operational USB wifi adapter.

Comment: @ShubhamNaik it means when there is a match, show also one line before it and 5 lines after it.